# Placing arrows in a tikz flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a flowchart with tikz. Below is my try. I would like the vertical arrow with superscript "a" to be connected with the horizontal arrow with superscript "n" and be more centered in the middle of the node "Step 3". Could you please tell me how I can do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}



\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{clrscode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=5cm, text width=5cm, minimum             height=1cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{name} = [rectangle, minimum width=5cm, text width=5cm, minimum     height=1cm, draw=black]

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\jacobi}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\congruent}[3]{$#1 \equiv #2 \text{ } \left( \text{mod } #3             \right)$}
\newcommand{\ZNZ}[1][n]{\mathbb{Z}/{#1}\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\ZNZX}[1][n]{(\mathbb{Z}/{#1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}
\newcommand{\QR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QNR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNRP}{\mathcal{QNR}_n^{+1}}
\newcommand{\JNP}{\mathcal{J}_n^{+1}}
\newcommand{\JNM}{\mathcal{J}_n^{-1}}



\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm]
        \node[name](alice){\textbf{Alice}};
        \node[process, below = of alice](step1){\textbf{Step 1:} Pick two     distinct large Blum primes $p$ and $q$ and set $n \coloneqq pq$.};


\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512943/strange-errors-in-tikz/512954#512954)  to your previous question: just add macro `join` to `box` options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
               chains,
               positioning}

\tikzset{
box/.style = {rectangle, draw,
              text width=5cm,
              minimum height=1cm},
arr/.style = {thick,-Stealth},
        }


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm,
  start chain = going below
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {box, on chain, join=by arr}] % <---
\node   (alice) {\textbf{Alice}};
\node   (step1) {\textbf{Step 1:} Pick two distinct large Blum primes 
                 $p$ and $q$ and set $n \coloneqq pq$.};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can draw  arrows separately with `\draw` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
               chains,
               positioning}

\tikzset{
box/.style = {rectangle, draw,
              text width=5cm,
              minimum height=1cm},
arr/.style = {thick,-Stealth},
        }


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm,
  start chain = going below
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {box, on chain}] 
\node   (alice) {\textbf{Alice}};
\node   (step1) {\textbf{Step 1:} Pick two distinct large Blum primes 
                 $p$ and $q$ and set $n \coloneqq pq$.};
    \end{scope}
\draw[arr] (alice) -- (step1); % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the nodes in the `tikzpicture` have the same style, i.e. use the same keys, you do not need to define a style for that. Rather, it suffices to say `nodes={<keys>}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,
  nodes={rectangle,minimum width=5cm,text width=5cm,minimum height=1cm,draw=black}]
 \node(alice){\textbf{Alice}};
 \node[below=of alice](step1){\textbf{Step 1:} Pick two distinct large Blum
 primes $p$ and $q$ and set $n \coloneqq p\,q$.};
 \draw[thick,-stealth] (alice) -- (step1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]